# Canvas Restart On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas html element that gets displayed when I click on a button.

The problem I am having is that the animation in the canvas only lasts about 1 second. So when I click on the button to change its CSS property from `display:none` to `display:inline`, the animation has already ended, as it was loading in the background.

What I want to happen is for the click on the button to simply restart the canvas animation. I dont mind that it is loading in the background, I just want it to restart on click of the button.

This is the html for the canvas and button:

```
    <canvas class="canvas2" id="canvas2"></canvas>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="two">Canvas 2</button>
    </div>
```

This is my javascript for the canvas. The animation is simply a bouncing square from left to right:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var c2 = canvas.getContext('2d');

c2.fillStyle = "black";
c2.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

var posX = 20;
posY = canvas.height / 2;
vx = 8, 
vy = -10;
gravity = 1;

setInterval(function(){
    c2.fillStyle = "black";
    c2.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    posX += vx;
    posY += vy;

    if (posY > 120){
        vy *= -0.5;
        vx *= 0.5;
        posY = 120;
    }

    vy += gravity;

    c2.fillStyle = "red";
    c2.fillRect(posX, posY, 10, 10);
}, 30);

});
```

And this is the simple jQuery used to show the canvas element:

```
$('.two').click(function() {
    $('.canvas2').show();
});
```

I've been trying out various functions but I cannot seem to get the canvas animation to restart when the button with class `two` is clicked.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Since you are never canceling the interval it should actually never stop, that should be a bigger concern of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/co047stc/

```js
var canvas, context;
var canvasDisplayed = false;
var intervalAnimation = null;
var posX, posY, vx, vy, gravity;

$('.two').click(function() {
  if (!canvasDisplayed) {
    showCanvas()
  }
  animation()
});

function showCanvas () {
 canvasDisplayed = true;
 canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

function resetSquare () {
 posX = 20;
  posY = canvas.height / 2;
  vx = 8, 
  vy = -10;
  gravity = 1;
}


function animation () {
 resetSquare()
 animationEnd()
  intervalAnimation = setInterval(function(){
    context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    posX += vx;
    posY += vy;

    if (posY > 120){
      vy *= -0.5;
      vx *= 0.5;
      posY = 120;
    }

    vy += gravity;

    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(posX, posY, 10, 10);
  }, 30);
}

function animationEnd () {
 context.fillStyle = "black";
 context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  clearInterval(intervalAnimation)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="canvas2" id="canvas2"></canvas>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="two">Canvas 2</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks perfect! Do you mind explaining what you changed?

Comment: Just separate code in functions, so `animation()` is called on button click and other functions concern just one action.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it into a function and only start it when the button is clicked:

```
function animation() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var c2 = canvas.getContext('2d');

    c2.fillStyle = "black";
    c2.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    var posX = 20;
    posY = canvas.height / 2;
    vx = 8, 
    vy = -10;
    gravity = 1;

    setInterval(function(){
        c2.fillStyle = "black";
        c2.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        posX += vx;
        posY += vy;

        if (posY > 120){
            vy *= -0.5;
            vx *= 0.5;
            posY = 120;
        }

        vy += gravity;

        c2.fillStyle = "red";
        c2.fillRect(posX, posY, 10, 10);
    }, 30);

    });
}


$('.two').click(function() {
    $('.canvas2').show();
    animation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this earlier. It does restart the animation, although because the canvas isn't cleared, the animation gets flickery. Is there a way to clear the canvas after the animation has executed?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect So in your case c2.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)